# Is this a bad practice in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Assuming that `someMethod()` returns an an array and I know the indexes:

`$myVar = $this->someMethod()['some_response_index'];`
Is this a bad idea?

Instead of doing this:

`$result = $this->someMethod();
 $myVar  = $result['some_response_index'];`

Comment: no, this is fine IMHO.

Comment: Why code two lines, when you can do it in one.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya ease of understanding by another coder....

Comment: It's exactly the same

Comment: I'd say no... unless you are going to need any other key, of course...

Comment: `someMethod` doesn't need to be run multiple times if you assign its return to `$result`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not a bad idea because it's clear what you are trying to achieve. It's called "[Array Dereferencing](https://www.xpertdeveloper.com/php-array-dereferencing/)" and has been available since PHP 5.4

Comment: Yep, the only "bad" thing here is that it somehow took till 5.4 for PHP to allow this!

Comment: Thank you!
I used to do that, and today my boss asked me if its a good practice, so I came here to the experts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a several part answer. You *can* do it it's valid PHP since [5.4](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), if you *know* the return array you will not run into a run-time error and it will work just fine.

Then again, for readability, if other people will look at your code and depending on the proficiency with the language it might not be super clear.

But in the end, it's personal preference. Just like writing things like

```
echo (new MyString('Hello World'))->replace('Hello', 'Foo')->replace('World', 'Bar');
```

valid PHP but for some perhaps not immediately clear what is going on.

If I saw your code I would most likely follow the function and check what it returns and then it would probably all make sense.

Comment: I think `$myVar = $this->someMethod()['some_response_index'];` is fine readability wise for anyone that knows how to work with arrays in PHP.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: Yea, I tend to agree... But I have seen very varying levels of PHP knowledge here so that is why I bring up the potential issue with it being less clear depending on who looks at it ofc. Everything will make sense to people who already know it :)